# Add directive in loop based on criteria

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a timeline.json like:

```
[{
 "from":"twitter",
  //...
},
{
 "from": "facebook"
//...
}]
```

Based on `from` attribute I need "render" specific directives: post-twitter or post-facebook **Inside a loop**

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. You can use ng-switch, ng-if, or a custom handler function in the link phase. You can find more info in the documentation.

Basically, switch between tags that invoke the directive based on a conditional statement, being it the 'from' value in your model. You can combine for example the ng-if directive with ng-include, to render a portion of your template based on this condition. Just make sure it won't degrade the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directive which compiles wanted directive depending on the passed argument.

Something like:

```
.directive('renderOther', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      type: '='
    },
    link: functtion(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var dir = $('<post-' + scope.type + '></post-'+scope.type+'>');
      dir.appendTo(elem);
      $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <render-other type="i.from"></render-other>
</div>
```

(Its not working code - just an idea)